# SQL query: How to perform this pivot-summarization?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to summarize daily transactions by "store hours" inferred from the actual transaction data I have.

I have the following StoreTransaction data:

```
StoreId    DayOfWeek    HourOfDay    TransactionCount
123        1            8            30
123        1            9            45
123        1            10           48
.
.
.
123        1            16           42
```

What's the SQL to pivot/summarize this into:

```
StoreId    DayOfWeek    HourFirst    HourLast    TotalTransactionCount
123        1            8            16          165
```

HourFirst would be the MIN(Hour) over StoreId/DayOfWeek, HourLast is MAX(Hour), and TotalTransactionCount would be SUM(TransactionCount) over StoreId/DayOfWeek.

Thanks!

Comment: "HourFirst would be the MIN(Hour) over StoreId/DayOfWeek, HourLast is MAX(Hour), and TotalTransactionCount would be SUM(TransactionCount) over StoreId/DayOfWeek." ... so what is the question?

Comment: You described the functions you need to use. Did you actually TRY anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aggregate function

```
select StoreId, 
DayOfWeek,   
min( HourOfDay ) as HourFirst,
max(HourOfDay ) as HourLast,
sum(TransactionCount) as TotalTransactionCount from yourtable
group by StoreId, DayOfWeek
```